# Is it fine to have just one attribute in a table,or is it cosidered as bad designing?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to connect a weak entity to some strong entity but weak entity just have one attribute ,so is it okay to have just one attribute in the entity or I will have to merge that attribute in the strong entity(merging is creating redundancy of).So I want to some advice on this confusion.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the data would look like?

Comment: One entity is of say "user data" including UID(PK), weak entity is "quiz" with quiz_Id(PK  and marks attribute on relation).Now one user can give any No. of quizes and single quiz can be given by any No. of users.E.g quiz_Id-1 can be given by both UID=1 and by UID=2 vice versa for quiz_Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases it may be over normalization, but judging by your example data I see nothing wrong with it, and in fact its probably the best way to deal with that many to many relationship.